# GAS: Alternative to using ScriptProperties.getProperty which is needed to retrieve events by ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I am learning GAS. The app script on the Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms uses the depecrated Class&method:ScriptProperties.getProperty(key) ie.ScriptProperties.getProperty('calId'). I have reported this as an issue to Google. Is there a better way to code this example and achieve similar results?

```
 // Store the ID for the Calendar, which is needed to retrieve events by ID.
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('calId', cal.getId());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is almost right..., it just uses a shortcut from the documentation without defining the shortcut itself.

The syntax is as follows

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key, value)
```

And all the similar methods as described in the documentation. (getProperty,setProperties , etc...)

The usage is the same, you can use find/replace in your script to simply update every occurrences .

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use Properties.setProperty(key, value) instead of ScriptProperties.setProperty(key, value)  The reason is because The "Properties Service" has now replaced Google's ScriptProperties class.  Here's my source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties